# Why won't this MySQL query return results by dates in the past?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of events that all have an event start date. What I want to do is create an event archive and display all the events that have come and gone.

Now for some reason I can get a result for events that have not yet passed but when I try select old events I get an empty result.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT wp_eventscalendar_main.eventTitle, wp_eventscalendar_main.eventDescription, wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate, wp_eventscalendar_main.postID, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
    FROM wp_eventscalendar_main, wp_postmeta 
    WHERE wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate < NOW() AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_eventscalendar_main.postID AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
    ORDER BY wp_eventscalendar_main.eventStartDate ASC 
    LIMIT 10
```

The eventStartDate is a date type if that makes any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see old events if you take out the date restriction entirely?

Comment: No issues with your code.  Did you try starting your where with one statement first.  See if it returns results.  then add the next one (post_id).  Finally check the results again, if you still see results then add the where (eventstartdate < now).  Check if you even have any data that matches those 3 conditions, they all must match (logical AND) to get ANY results.

Comment: I've worked it out guys. Thanks for reminding me to go back to basics before panicking!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to use INNER JOIN not [CROSS JOINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#.CE.B8-join_and_equijoin). You do this with the INNER JOIN keyword. And, i recommend start using aliases, it's more readable.

So, something like this:

```
SELECT m.eventTitle, m.eventDescription, m.eventStartDate, m.postID, p.post_id, p.meta_key, p.meta_value 
FROM wp_eventscalendar_main m INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p 
ON (m.postID = p.post_id)
WHERE m.eventStartDate < NOW() 
 AND p.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
ORDER BY m.eventStartDate ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Now, do you have rows that satisfy eventStartDate < NOW() ? Check that. Just remove that statement, do something like this:

```
SELECT m.eventTitle, m.eventDescription, m.eventStartDate, m.postID, p.post_id, p.meta_key, p.meta_value 
FROM wp_eventscalendar_main m INNER JOIN wp_postmeta p 
ON (m.postID = p.post_id)
WHERE
p.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
ORDER BY m.eventStartDate ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

Do you get any result?